# How do I authenticate only particular users into using the site?

Tags: django, django-templates

I want the users, who have the email, that has the domain name  '@example.com', to be able to use the buttons, that directs them to different url patterns.

To carry out the above operation, I have created the following in my templates. Here is code snippet of my template

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
                  
     <a href="{% url 'quizlist' %}" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg">Quizzes</a>
     <a href="{% url 'profile' %}" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg">Profile</a>
     <a href="{% url 'logout' %}" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg mr-2">Log Out</a>
                  
{% else %}
     <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <a href="{% url 'register' %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg mr-2">Register</a>
        <a href="{% url 'login' %}" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg">Log In</a>
     </div>
{% endif %}
```

But this authenticates all logged in users and not only the users with a particular domain name. So  any thoughts on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Create Authentication

Django app and define a custom authentication backend class that inherits from django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend. Override the authenticate method to include your domain-based authentication logic.

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()

class DomainEmailBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=username)
            if user.email.endswith('@example.com') and user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Update your Project Settings:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'path.to.custom_auth_backends.DomainEmailBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
]
```

Your html example;

```
{% if user.is_authenticated and user.email|lower.endswith('@example.com') %}
    <a href="{% url 'quizlist' %}" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg">Quizzes</a>
    <a href="{% url 'profile' %}" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg">Profile</a>
    <a href="{% url 'logout' %}" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg mr-2">Log Out</a>
{% else %}
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <a href="{% url 'register' %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg mr-2">Register</a>
        <a href="{% url 'login' %}" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg">Log In</a>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```